# Facebook publish api parameters, some of them don't seem work

Tags: facebook, publish

I'm trying to build a FB app which has a function of publishing post with picture to news feed.

I am able to do that via FB's graph api according to FB's developer document,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/feed
```

with the parameters such as `message, picture, link, name, caption`. These are parameters listed in [FB's doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). I assumed that these parameters are only for the POST requests.

For [posts in FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), we can find more parameters. I assumed they are only for the GET requests.

However, when I tested all these parameters, I found that I am able to add `actions` to my POST requests and get customized actions. When I try to add `message_tags, from, to`, these parameters don't work in POST requests.

So, I get confused. Is my assumption correct? Or I did something wrong.

BTW, when I send requests with these parameters, no error message returns. Posts are published to news feed, but no `message_tags, from, to`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the Documentation of the Object you are creating the Post for (the PROFILE_ID), you will get more explicit information about GET and POST API limitations. Here is documentation for Posts to a User:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

It says when creating a Post (using the POST method) you can define these properties:

- message
- link
- picture
- name
- caption
- description
- actions
- privacy
- object_attachment

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know the description of creating a post is in the "User" category.

Comment: BTW, for actions it seems FB onlys support one action right now. I tried array of "name"s and "link"s. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @XiaomoLiu for some reason, I can't even get one action to work :(